# Как переопределить System.FormatException?

Tags: c#, исключения

Вопрос в следующем есть следующий код `

```
try
{
   int a=int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}`
```

Существует ли способ не прописывать try catch каждый раз,а переопределить поведение System.FormatException,чтобы выводило сообщение на экране например,а не выкидывало из программы?

Comment: Специально для этого добавляются безопасные реализации же - `TryParse`

Comment: Ага, а если другое место в коде тоже использует `System.FormatException`, то там неожиданно выброс исключения должен пропасть? Такой подход годился бы для маленьких программ, но совершенно не катит для сколько-нибудь объёмных проектов.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вариант 1. Для глобального решения в пределах всего аппликейшена - при старте инициализируем перехват эксепшенов:

```
namespace myApp
{
    static class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Application.ThreadException += new System.Threading.ThreadExceptionEventHandler(Application_ThreadException);
            // здесь запускаемся...
        }
    }
}
```

в методе обрабатываем прерывание:

```
    static void Application_ThreadException(object sender, System.Threading.ThreadExceptionEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Exception as System.FormatException != null)
        {
            //TODO что-то
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Вариант 2. Можем продублировать упомянутые уже TryParce, но с собственной реализацией:

```
public static class MyParseClass
{
    public static bool Parse(object inParam, out outParam)
    {
        try
        {
            outParam=int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            outParam = 0;
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

.NET использует механизм исключений для обработки ошибок, это не изменить ни каким способом, но в вашем случае можно сам код написать по-другому, например так, чтобы пользователь вводил число до тех пор, пока не сделает это правильно:

```
int a;
while(!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out a))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Веденное значение не число, повторите ввод");
}
Console.WriteLine(a);
```

Answer (score 0):

По хорошему в подобной ситуации нужно обрабатывать исключения определённого типа.

```
try
{
    //Делаем что-то
}
catch(FormatException ex)
{
   //Делаем что-то другое
}
```

Comment: Оно понятно,но если я множество переменных объявляю в разных местах,есть ли способ каждый раз это не прописывать?Использование метода не вариант,это тоже загромождает код.

Comment: @FaradeyInimicos каким образом использование метода загромождает код? А вообще разумное решение вынести это в метод, а там хоть исключения с логгированием, хоть TryParse