# Вместо ошибки входная строка имела неверный формат, выводить свое сообщение

Tags: c#, обработка-данных

В общем и целом , мне нужно , что если пользователь по случайности при вводе age просто жмет Enter:
То выводится сообщение: "Возраст не может быть пустым! :("
В данный момент просто пишет входная строка имела неверный формат.
Возможно ли вообще такое реализовать?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                Console.Write("Введите возраст котика: ");

                int age = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                if (Age == 0)
                {
                    throw new Exception("Возраст котика не может быть пустым! :( ");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Ошибка: {e.Message}");
            }
            Console.Read();
        }
```

Comment: Используйте int.TryParse и если он вернет false, то верните что то более общее, например  "Возраст указан не верно", а то вам придется отдельно проверять пустуя строку, нечисловые символы в ней и т.п.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string ageString = Console.ReadLine();
if (ageString == "") {
  Console.WriteLine("Возраст котика не может быть пустым! :( ");
} else {
  int age = int.Parse(ageString);
  ...
}
```

Comment: Спасибо. Помогло

Comment: Интересно, кто плюсует такие скудные и непонятные ответы? Здесь можно было вполне вменяемый пост написать с объяснением, как всякие `Parse` и `TryParse` работают. Кому такой ответ может быть полезен кроме автора вопроса? Я бы и сам написал ответ, но вопрос - [дубликат](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/516675/373567). Поставлю-ка минусы обоим.